# Ошибка в phalcon yonacms

Tags: php, phalcon, yonacms

При создании страницы ругается на

> $transliterated = \Transliterator

**Fatal error: Class 'Transliterator' not found in D:\Servera\Last\OpenServer\domains\ren\app\modules\Application\Localization\Transliterator.php on line 18**

```
 class Transliterator
    {

        public static function slugify($string)
        {
            $prepared       = str_replace(
                    array('я', 'ю', 'ї', 'є', 'ж', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ь'), array('ya', 'yu', 'yi', 'ye', 'zh', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', ''), $string);
            $transliterated = \Transliterator::create('Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; [:Punctuation:] Remove; Lower();')->transliterate($prepared);

            $clean = preg_replace('/\W/i', '-', $transliterated);

            $replaced = str_replace('--', '-', $clean);
            $result   = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $replaced);

            return $result;

        }

    }
```

Нашел что то такое http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php
Почему не работает не пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо установить пакет `intl`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Comment: Это русскоязычный stackoverflow. Пожалуйста, переведите Ваш ответ.

Comment: `D:\Servera\` (Windows) в вопросе может указывать, что `sudo apt-get` (Ubuntu) не сработает.